# AWS Glue creates a new temp table everytime a new file replaces a new file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We are receiving a new file daily from a third-party system in our s3 bucket. From this s3 bucket, we copy the data into another s3 bucket. The file name is results.parquet. We run daily a Glue crawler which runs on destination folder path in destination bucket to create a new table ltv_results.

We have return a Python script for copying this file from one S3 to another S3. This Python script does two things:

1. Deletes the file results.parquet in destination S3 bucket from yesterday.
2. Copies the new file received today results.parquet from source to destination S3 location.

The destination folder structure is as :

`s3://destination_bucket_name/ecomm_prod/act/ltv_results/app_id=APP-0103/` . Inside this folder we copy the file results.parquet.

Due to this path compatible with Hive standards, the ltv_results is partitioned based on app_id column.

Each day a new file with same name replaces the old file.

The python scripts deletes the contents in s3 from path `'s3://destination_bucket_name/ecomm_prod'`, so ltv_results folder is created daily with app_id.

The problem is that when we run the Glue crawler on same file multiple times, it does not detect the change and do not do anything, which is correct. But when on next day, as a new file comes, instead of dropping the table and refreshing the table with new file contents, it creates a new table ltv_results_88434343 and stores the data into that table.

I read that Glue reads only the incremental data. I want that Glue should only refresh the data daily in the table and not create a new table every day when new file gets copied in destination folder.

Comment: silly question, do you need to run the crawler every day? I mean the crawler is used to discover your data structure (ex. columns and types, partitions, ...) then save this metadata in the Glue catalog so you can query it using tools like Athena. If your data structure does not evolve you don't have to run it systematically.

Comment: @MarcC - I agree but if the file at s3 location is changed for the Athena table, will it get reflected everyday without running crawler?

Comment: In my experience it works, the only issue is when you push new partitions (ex. app_id=APP-0104/), even new files is not an issue (ex. results2.parquet)

Comment: Ok got it. So need to run the crawler only when a new partition is added in S3. Is there any way to identify whether a new partition got added in the s3 location so we can run the crawler in that case only?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Actually the concept of folder in S3 is just a file prefix, and you can trigger a Lambda when a new file is added to a bucket, this Lambda can trigger the crawler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the crawler is needed only to discover the schema of the data, and if the schema doesn't change, there is no need to rerun the crawler.

More than that, it is important to understand that Athena is not a standard database that loads the data. The Glue table is only a mapping for the query engine on how to find and parse the data in S3.

If you only replace one parquet file with the same schema in the exact location (as defined in the Glue table), the query engine will query that new file without changing anything.

If you want to add new data (daily, for example), you can simply put it in the exact folder location, or create a new folder under the root location, and update the partition mapping of Glue with `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <TABLE_NAME>`

Another option is to drop the old table (remember that it is only the mapping of the data, not the data itself) and recreate the table with the crawler. This is a good option if the schema of the data changes frequently.